# Woocommerce (2.1.x or up) Show Empty Categories In Product Category Widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, woocommerce

I had woocommerce 2.0.x on my site. By default, Woocommerce doesn't show empty categories in the "Product Category Widget" so I used the following solution to show the empty categories.

```
function woocommerce_show_empty_categories($cat_args){
    $cat_args['hide_empty']=0;
    return $cat_args;
}
```

Now after I have updated to version 2.2, the hack doesn't work anymore. I tried all over the internet and they say that the above hack won't work for the update version. But I still can see the "woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args" in Wocommerce's "class-we-widget-product-categories.php" file which I think is controlling the Product Category Widget.
I have tried to use [this solution](https://github.com/growdev/woocommerce/commit/bf8a825f2d7cfe3e51197ddba10d60c75f382d64) but it's a little messy for me, I can't understand how to apply it.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: Just to point you in the right direction...if you [view the source](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/506a66b3a43de4d59eb47f1efc7eae920c4256ab/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-product-categories.php), you'll notice that this is now part of `get_terms( 'product_cat', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) )`. Also, not sure what's wrong with the solution you linked. Looks perfectly clean to me.

Comment: I don't really know..That is why I am a bit fussy now because the same problem is all over the internet that above solution have stopped working after the latest update

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem described after upgrade.

My investigation found that the problem is in function display_elements of WC_Product_Cat_Dropdown_Walker:

```
if (!$element || 0 === $element->count) {
    return;
}
```

Which filters out empty categories. To fix it, and maintain backward compatibility with the known filter, I check the presence of the hide_empty value in the $args variable

```
$hide_empty_var = ( isset( $args[0]['hide_empty'] ) ? $args[0]['hide_empty'] : true );
if (!$element || (0 === $element->count && $hide_empty_var)) {
    return;
}
```

This same logic must be used in the dropdown walker.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting few hours on this issue.Finally found it.
Just avoid any code and install this plugin 
 ['Booster for Woocommerce'](http://wpfavs.com/plugin/woocommerce-jetpack/)
It's doing what exactly you need.